# DELETE-OUTPUT-INTO performance

Tags: sql-server

At first I would like to place two code samples

#### Sample 1

```
INSERT INTO TableB
SELECT *
FROM
 TableA AS A
WHERE
 A.SomeColumn = @someValue

DELETE A
FROM 
  TableA AS A
WHERE
  A.SomeColumn = @someValue
```

#### Sample 2

```
DELETE A
FROM
  TableA As A
OUTPUT
  DELETED.*
INTO
  TableB
WHERE
  A.SomeColumn = @someValue
```

Here, two codes satisfy the same goal. We are actually moving some rows from **TableA** to **TableB**.

Which code sample should perform better? Does the performance of `DELETE-OUTPUT-INTO` clause depend on the amount of deleted rows?

Comment: *"Which code sample should perform better?"* What do *your* tests tell you? You're the one with the objects (with all their relevant indexes), data, etc. Why not run both (within a transaction, so you can roll it back) and check the relevant statistics, query plans, etc, and find out? That would be the far easier way than asking us, which will could just as likely be "it depends" as "Answer A" or "Answer B"; as we know nothing about your environment.

Comment: The test result is inconsistent. Sometimes `Sample 1` performs better and vice-versa. I am not sure if it is due to server load or amount of data or something else?

Comment: Well then include all the details we need. Query plans, DDL with indexes, IO statistics, etc, etc.